# What is the role of processing editor in a journal submission?

Tags: paper-submission, journal-workflow

I submitted a paper to a high impact factor journal in my field a 4 days ago. Today, I received a email from the journal editor with the following description:

> Thank you for your recent submission to TTT journal. XYZ will be the processing editor for your paper referenced above.
>
> Your submission has been been assigned the following manuscript number: ARBITRARY007.
>
> You will hear from the processing editor's office when the review process is complete (please allow 2-3 months for this).

So, what does this mean? Will it go to the reviewers and take 2-3 months for review? Or will it take 2-3 months for the processing editor to decide if it should be sent to reviewers for getting reviewed or be rejected?

What's the role of processing editor in this workflow?

Comment: Seems to clearly say the review process will take 2-3 months.

Answer (score 1):

The email clearly says that you will hear from the processing editor's office when the review process is complete, and that the review process will take 2-3 months - so your first interpretation is correct, it will go to the reviewers who are expected to finish reviewing in 2-3 months.

Taking 2-3 months to decide to send the paper to review would be pretty extreme.